# Postgis trigger : table and materialized view

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, postgis, materialized-views

I have a postgis polygons table for my "cities".
I have a point table for my "boreholl".

I created a "mv" materialized view defined by a spatial join as follows:

```
SELECT boreholl.*,
cities.gid,
cities.insee_id,
cities.name
FROM boreholl, cities
WHERE st_intersects(boreholl.geom, cities.geom);
```

Now I want as soon as an updating takes place for the "cities_name" column of my "cities" polygon table,
this change also occurs in the "name" column of my materialized view.

As far i understood,the trigger must be defined on the "cities" table as follows :

```
CREATE TRIGGER cities_trigger
after  update
on cities
FOR EACH STATEMENT. 
execute procedure trigger_fonction
```

Now I need to define the function. It is for this step that I need you.
Below, a proposed structure. But a lot is missing :

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION  trigger_fonction
returns trigger
langage sql
AS $$
BEGIN
 if    then
update
end if ;
return new
refresh materialized view
END;
$$
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest approach is to create a trigger on a specific column and every time this column gets updated `mv` will be refreshed.:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION rebuild_materialized_view() 
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
  REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW mv;
  RETURN NEW;
END; $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The correct syntax of column specific triggers is `...OF colum_name ON table_name...`, not only `...ON table_name...`. Also, you probably want to refresh the view also in case of an `INSERT`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER cities_trigger
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF name ON cities
FOR EACH STATEMENT 
EXECUTE PROCEDURE rebuild_materialized_view();
```

The downside of this approach is that `mv` will be refreshed regardless of intersection between the updated record and `boreholl`. Depending on the size of your tables this shouldn't be an issue though.

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=e5d45fc8918dc5c29e1bc006c6f7b04b)

A further (slightly more complex) approach would be to use the values of `TG_OP`. If the trigger is being called with an `INSERT` and if the new record intersects with `boreholl`, the materialized view `mv` gets refreshed. If it is an `UPDATE` and the updated record was previously in `mv` and `name` was changed, `mv` also gets refreshed:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION rebuild_materialized_view() 
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
  IF TG_OP ='INSERT' AND EXISTS (SELECT ST_Intersects(NEW.geom,b.geom) 
                                 FROM boreholl b) THEN
     REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW mv;
  ELSEIF TG_OP = 'UPDATE' AND 
       EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM mv 
               WHERE gid = NEW.gid AND NEW.name <> OLD.name) THEN
      REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW mv;
  END IF;

  RETURN NEW;
END; $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER cities_trigger
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON cities
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE rebuild_materialized_view();
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=e31312067eb9158ffd88a3b87ae65eb1)